# NancyFX stops handling requests from multiple clients after a while on Linux Mono

Tags: linux, mono, nancy

I have a server application written in NancyFX which runs on Ubuntu server on Mono. I am hitting the server app with 80+ clients calling simple POST route to update some data to the app database. The route is fast, it just returns "success" string. The clients hit the server every minute all together (more or less). The problem is that when I restart the server app all runs OK but after few minutes the server app gets stucked and stops handling requests. When I check the server app process on the linux server it has exactly 107 threads. No more threads are added or removed. I tried to restart the server app and I always end up with the same results. NancyFX is the latest version 1.4.2. Linux server is Ubuntu server 3.13.0-24-generic. Mono is also the latest version. Nancy is owin self-hosted.

Any idea what should I check or change? Even if my hosts hit non-existing route I end up with the same result so I assume the problem is not in my modules. Is there some nancy settings? Should I change something on my linux server?

Comment: what does `latest version of mono` exactly mean for you?

Comment: Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4+rpi1)
But the problem vas somewhere else. I tried to implement signalR but it didn't work properly and after I removed all referencies to it it started working.

Comment: latest version of mono is 4.2.x (stable), 4.3.x (master)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a fairly old question but it's possible that your issue pertains to a timeout lock that was [reported](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/2533) and [patched](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/pull/2534/files) in the v2.0 development branch. They haven't backported it to the stable v1.4.x branch yet but the patch looks pretty trivial to me so you could make your own fork.

The behaviour you described is the same as the behaviour I have seen so I believe we experienced the same issue. Unfortunately it's difficult to say whether this fixed the problem but I hope this helps somebody in the future!

**Update:** Since patching the latest Nancy 1.4.x with the patch linked above, we have not seen any further intermittent timeouts in our production environment in the last 4 months or so.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think it was more cause by SignalR which I was using wrongly because after I removed it all went normal. But what you are saying  might be other potential issue so it is good to point it out.